# How to return `void` as a generic return type in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

How to handle a case when proc returns `void` as generic return type `T`?

Example - when reading a file we have return value - the file content, but when writing a file there's no return value.

[playground](https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2KAk)

```
import sugar

proc open_file[T](path: string, cb: (proc (file: string): T)): T =
  cb("file descriptor")

proc read_file(path: string): string =
  open_file(path, (file) => "file content")


proc write_file(path, content: string): void =
  discard open_file(path, proc (file: auto): bool =
    echo "writing content to file"
    false
  )
  
echo read_file("/some-path")
write_file("/some-path", "some content")
```

Is there a better way than a workaround in this example - when we returning something (false) and discarding it?

Answer (score 3):

You're making a big misunderstanding here - the `discard` that you use is related to the return value in `open_file`, it's not related to the `void` in your `write_file` at all.

`void` as a return type is superficial (doesn't need to be specified when there's no return type) and it literally means "return nothing" (it's not like C's void), but Nim requires you to handle return values from any procedures unless they are marked as `{.discardable.}`

So in your code example, there are no workarounds at all, it's normal Nim code (except for the fact that `void` is not required to be written) - see https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#statements-and-expressions-discard-statement

Comment: But if I remove the `discard` the code won't be compiled, please check the [playground with the same code with the discard removed](https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2KBZ)

Comment: That's exactly what I said - discard in your code has nothing to do with the return value of write_file, discard is needed when you literally ignore (discard) the return value of some call, in this case you want to ignore the return value of open_file

Comment: I understand that discard is not related to my question, but using discard was the easiest way to make that code work. Is there a better way to make that code work?

Comment: as @Yardanico says, if you mark open_file as {.discardable.} you don't need the discard